# PFRelation create with UiButton on Cell

Tags: ios, parse-platform, relation

I'm trying to create PFRelation using a button in a TableView with custom cell, but I can not create these relationships, I only creates a relationship with a specific user regardless of the cell that I select. ..

Where am I doing wrong?

```
    - (IBAction)FFAddAmiciAction:(id)sender {
             NSIndexPath *indexPath = [[self tableView] indexPathForSelectedRow];
            PFObject *searchedUser = [self.objects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            PFUser *user = [PFUser currentUser  ];
             PFRelation *relation = [user relationforKey:@"Amic"];
               [relation addObject:searchedUser];
                 [user saveInBackground];
}
```

Comment: Did you debug and check what `indexPath` is set to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you tap a button on a cell it usually would not cause the cell to be set to `selected`. That means that when you call `indexPathForSelectedRow` you could often get the wrong result.

You might want to look at using a different way to get the index path of the row associated with the button, there are many potential options, maybe:

1. Teach the button about the index path (possibly with `objc_setAssociatedObject`)
2. Use `indexPathForRowAtPoint:` to get the row based on the center point of the button (remember to convert coordinate space)

---

Typed in so check syntax and spelling...

```
CGPoint point = [(UIButton *)sender convertPoint:[(UIButton *)sender center] toView:[self tableView]];
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [[self tableView] indexPathForRowAtPoint:point];
```

Comment: Hello thanks for the answers ... Wain unfortunately are still at the beginning and these steps are very specific but efficient ... Could you give me a practical example of one of the two based on the code I provided above? Let me try to understand and deepen to avoid errors that may compromise the function :(

Comment: Thanks Wain, I tried to enter the code but the result is always the same as before ... surely I'm wrong ... The code that I have provided to be inserted so as you wrote? or must be modified in particular

Comment: CGPoint point = [(UIButton *)sender convertPoint:[(UIButton *)sender center] toView:[self tableView]];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [[self tableView] indexPathForRowAtPoint:point];
PFObject *searchedUser = [self.objects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    PFUser *user = [PFUser currentUser  ];
    PFRelation *relation = [user relationforKey:@"Amic"];
    [relation addObject:searchedUser];
        [user saveInBackground];

Comment: The Tableview also implements a search bar with a display controller, it could also be that the problem?

Comment: That could also be a problem if you are sending messages to the wrong table view... You really need to debug to check what the `indexPath` is.